# Print variables separated by "-" using awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am trying to print all numbers between two values separated by "-".
I have a document with multiple rows looking like this:

```
14 - 19 |
45 - 50 |
```

I want to have a result like:

```
14 15 16 17 18 19  
45 46 47 48 49 50
```

But I keep getting all the values in the same row, although I have set ORS and OFS.

Is there anything I might be missing?

```
#!/bin/bash
awk ' BEGIN{OFS=" ";
            RS="|";
            FS=" ";
            ORS=" "};
{
  for (i=1; i<=NF ; i++)
  {
    if ($i == "-")
    {
      st=$(i-1);
      en=$(i+1);
      st++;
      while (st < en)
      {
         print st;
         st++;
      }
    }
    else
        print $i;
  }
}' list.txt
```

Comment: You know you could put that `awk` script into its own file with a `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` line at the top, and then run it as its own script with the filename as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the fields are fixed, this is much more simple and direct:

```
$ awk '{for (i=$1+0;i<=$(NF-1);i++){printf "%d ", i};print ""}' list.txt
14 15 16 17 18 19 
45 46 47 48 49 50
```

To prevent trailing space (thanks @fedorqui):

```
awk '{for (i=$1+0;i<$3+0;i++){printf "%d ", i};print ""$3}' list.txt
```

Comment: Or to prevent a trailing space at the end of the line: `{for (i=$1; i<$2; i++) printf "%d%s", i, OFS; printf "%d%s", $2, ORS}`.

Comment: Thank you! It works and it i much simpler than may script!

Comment: 2 cents using while . awk '{while($1++<$3-1)printf $1OFS ; print $3}' file

Answer (score 1):

Each `print` is treated as a separate record, so it adds the `ORS` at the end.

You can use `printf` istead:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk ' BEGIN{
            RS="|";
            FS=" ";};
{
  for (i=1; i<=NF ; i++)
  {
    if ($i == "-")
    {
      st=$(i-1);
      en=$(i+1);
      st++;
      while (st < en)
      {
         printf "%d ", st;
         st++;
      }
    }
    else
        printf "%d " $i;
  }
  printf "\n"
}' list.txt
```

Comment: This solution is good also if the rows aren't of standard format. Such as: 2054 |
127 1702 - 1705 1707 1710 - 1713 1715 1723 1728 |
3061 3082 3526 3725 |